# Splitting a huge text file (2Gb+) into 2 chunks in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I have a gigantic text file with two columns (floats). I would like to split them into two files, each containing approximately the same number of rows. What is the best way to do this? I am using VS 2012. The file size is approximately 2Gb.

Comment: "text file with two columns", "split them into two files, each containing approximately the same number of columns". so 1? approximately

Comment: I'm pretty sure he meant same number of rows.

Comment: I meant rows. Thanks. Edited. pst: How long will this take? These files are huge and I don't have an SSD.

Comment: do you mean each one containing the approx same number of rows?

Comment: I would just use cut or grep.

Comment: @Markus  split would be the way to go if he were on a unix system.  But it seems he's working in windows

Comment: If the line length is approximately constant , you could take the file length, divide by two, jump there , find next line break and cut from there.

Comment: @AntillarMaximus may it be in terminal?

Comment: @MarkusMikkolainen Good idea - that could eliminate one write stream (with a truncate) and still maintain an approximate split. It would also eliminate the need for further line-by-line processing.

Comment: I don't have access to *nix, but terminal is ok. My perl script crashes so I was a bit despondent.

Comment: @AntillarMaximus Maybe just fix the perl program .. you're not "slurping" the file by chance?

Comment: Perl program is too noobish. Here it is:   open (IN,"2013_03_20_0010d.txt");
open (OUT1,">2013_03_20_0010d_split_1.txt");
open (OUT2,">2013_03_20_0010d_split_2.txt");

$c = 0;
while($line = <IN>) {$c++;}
$keep = $c/2.; 
close(IN);

open(IN,"test.txt");

for($i=0; $i <$keep; $i++){ $line = <IN>; print OUT1 $line;}
for($i=0; $i <$keep; $i++){ $line = <IN>; print OUT2 $line;}

Comment: Do you need to preserve the sequence? If not, you could read the file two lines at a time, and write one line to each output file.

Comment: This works for small files but blows up on large files.

Comment: @AntillarMaximus Unless this *needs* to be C++ (or that is another requirement), considering closing this question and focusing on the Perl (in another question).

Comment: I prefer C++ because I plan on migrating the rest of the code (digitizing etc).

Comment: @AntillarMaximus So why not just write the equivalent of that Perl code in C++? (Consider how it differs from my recommendation and it requires a full-read first which doubles the read IO. If it happens to be "too slow", then I'd consider something like Markus suggested which can reduce the IO writes by about half.)

Comment: @AntillarMaximus have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541433/split-a-large-file-in-c

Comment: why do you need to split it? you could also open the file twice and first time skip half of the file, fast forward to the next linebreak, then start reading from that point. one filedescriptor reads from start to mid+epsilon, other from mid+epsilon to end.

Answer (score 1):

there is a free tool, Windows file splitter called [HJSplit](http://www.hjsplit.org/)
it can split files of any type and size.
or [this](http://www.gdgsoft.com/gsplit/).
you can also use grep in cygwin on windows or do it in powershell

[and here it is done in C++: related question:]
([Split a Large File In C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541433/split-a-large-file-in-c))

Answer (score 1):

The code really needs to be "started" by you. In any case, here is a collection of my thoughts - I've also borrowed from other commenters.

My approach, pseudo-code:

```
open I for reading
open O1 for writing
open O2 for writing
while I has input:
   write next line from I into O1
   if I has input:
       write next line from I into O2
```

Notice how, unlike the Perl approach, it doesn't require reading the file once-through first to read the number of lines. This is a reduction of read IO by about half. However, like the perl approach, it still works on a line-by-line basis and requires line scanning/processing. Since this algorithm is streaming (the line is only held long enough to be written), it should function across all file sizes. Buffering output streams is very critical for performance.

The approach suggested by Markus Mikkolainen is similar to:

```
open I for reading
seek to midpoint of I using filesize/2
scan backward to line start
open O1 for writing
write bytes 0..(mid line start + length) from I to O1
open O2 for writing
write bytes (mid line start + length)..filesize from I to O2
```

If the input file can be modified then only the writes to O2 need to be done, followed by an appropriate *truncate* on I. This could result in about half the IO writes of my approach and, since it deals with a plain byte copy, avoids line-by-line processing after the start of the midpoint line is located.

As long as the lines have a uniform length distribution, this approach will result in approximately the same number of lines appearing in both output files; on the other hand, even if the line lengths differ wildly in a skewed fashion, both output files will be approximately the same size.

Now get coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "split" command in Unix. Cygwin if you're on Windows.

Comment: Yep. That wheel was invented a long time ago.